# Python list traversal with gaps

Tags: python

Hi I have a multidimensional list such as:

```
my_list = [[1,2,3,1,2],[1,0,3,1,2],[1,0,0,0,2],[1,0,3,0,2]]
```

where 0 represents a gap between two pieces of data.

What I need to do is iterate through the list and keep track of how many gaps are in each sublist and throw away the zeros. I think the best way is to break each sublist into chunks where there are zeros so I end up with smaller lists of integers and a number of gaps. Ideally, to form a new list which tells me the length of each chunk and number of gaps (i.e. chunks -1), such as:

```
new_list = [[5, 0], [[1, 3], 1], [[1, 1], 1], [[1, 1, 1], 2]]
```

or probably better:

```
new_list = [[5], [1, 3], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

and I will know that the gaps are equal to len(chunk).

**EDIT:**
However, leading and trailing zeros do not represent gaps. i.e. [0,0,1,2] represents one continuous chunk.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What are you planning on doing with this?  Could you use a `numpy` masked array instead?

Comment: Sorry. Basically I want the new list represent the chunks of integers (as length), where a zero in the original list represented a gap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is perfect for this:

```
from itertools import groupby
my_list = [[1,2,3,1,2],[1,0,3,1,2],[1,0,0,0,2],[1,0,3,0,2]]
new_list = [[len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(inner, bool) if k] for inner in my_list]
```

Result:

```
>>> new_list
[[5], [1, 3], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

The result contains the length of each non-zero chunk for each sublist, so for example `[1,0,3,1,2]` gives `[1,3]`, so there are two chunks (one gap).  This matches your second output format.

Comment: That seems really close, and quite advaced for me. However, I tried it with a list where the last element is `[0,0,2,3]` and the result is `[2]`. In this instance the result should be `[1]` (i.e. no gaps).

Comment: it fails for `[0,0,1,2] `, returns `2` for it. the correct answer should be 1, see the Edit.

Comment: Yes. Leading and trailing zeros seem to be the issue. I realise I could go through the list and remove trailing and leading zeros first, but then I loose some of the elegance of @F.J.s answer.

Comment: How is that the wrong result?  The `[2]` that you get for `[0,0,2,3]` means that there are no gaps (length of result minus 1 is number of gaps).  `[0,0,2,3]`, `[2,3,0,0]`, and `[0,2,3,0]`, and `[2,3]` will all give `[2]` to indicate that there are two consecutive non-zero elements without gaps.

Comment: Actually zero represents the gaps. So the leading zeros in `[0,0,2,3]` mean that there is a gap of two places between nothing and the first integer. In my mind this is not a gap. A gap only exists *between* two integers.

Comment: @F.J If there is some way to modify your answer to take account of this, then  I will accept it.

Comment: Can you explain why the result for `[0,0,2,3]` should be `[1]`?  This seems inconsistent with the problem statement.  Note that the result my answer gives is based on your second example output, which doesn't show the number of gaps but the length of each non-zero chunk.

Comment: If only integers are counted as a continuous chunk, then `2,3` represents only one continuous chunk. The leading (or trailing zeros) are essentially irrelevant here. I'm sorry if that was not made clear.

Comment: If `[1,2,3,1,2]` should give `[5]`, then `[2,3]` should give `[2]`, and if `[0,0,2,3]` should be the same as `[2,3]` since leading zeros are irrelevant, then it should also give `[2]`.  That is how I interpreted it and I'm still not sure how that is wrong.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20353/discussion-between-darwin-tech-and-f-j)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my humble code without any imports:

The algorithm is slightly long:

```
def toggle(n):
    return n != 0



def chunk_counter(L):
    """
    list -> list
    """

    chunk_list = []
    pivots = []
    for j in range(len(L)):
        if j == 0 and toggle(L[0]):
            pivots.append(j)
        elif toggle(L[j]) and toggle(L[j]) != toggle(L[j-1]):
            pivots.append(j)

    for m in range(len(pivots)):
        k = 0
        if m == len(pivots)-1:
            bound = len(L)
        else:
            bound = pivots[m+1]

        p = 0
        while p in range(bound - pivots[m]):
            if toggle(L[pivots[m] + p]):
                    k += 1
                    p += 1
            else:
                p += 1
        chunk_list.append(k)

    return chunk_list        


    def chunks(L):
    """
    (list of lists) -> list of lists
    """

    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(L)):
        new_list.append(chunk_counter(L[i]))

    return new_list
```

So, you may try the function `chunks()` on your list:

```
>>> L = [[1,2,3,1,2],[1,0,3,1,2],[1,0,0,0,2],[1,0,3,0,2], [0,0,1,2]]
>>> chunks(L)
[[5], [1, 3], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [2]]
```

Here's a recursive definition (a replacement for Chunk Counter):

```
    counter_list = []
def counter(L):
    k = 0
    while(k < len(L) and L[k] != 0):
        k +=1
    counter_list.append(k)
    if k == len(L):
        print counter_list
    else:
    counter(L[k+1:])
```